# Saving data over multiple pages with java web-application

Tags: java, web-applications, thymeleaf

I was looking for a way to store information so I can use a specific variabele multiple times.
If the user gives his/her name, I want to be able to set the name at the top of each page.

I already tried to use this in my controller.

```
public String login(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    gebruikersnaam = request.getParameter("gebruikersnaam");
    gebruikerRepository.gebruikersnaamOpslaan();
    gebruikerRepository.getGebruiker(gebruikersnaam);
    return "/index";
}
```

Thank you in advanced
Jonas

Comment: I think you can put it in model, it should be staying as long as u put it there. May be you also need a hidden variable in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `gebruikerRepository` is the pojo class, you need to use a setter method like `gebruikerRepository.setGebruiker(gebruikersnaam)` to set the name into variable `gebruiker`.

Use `gebruikerRepository.getGebruiker()` to retrieve the variable.